# Is "Good luck!" considered passive-aggressive?

Tags: phrase-usage

I want to make an educational Instagram post and don't know how to end it with a short phrase in the last picture. So I wrote 'Good luck!' but I'm not sure about its tone. It's good in terms of length but I think it might be considered as passive-aggressive or just weird.

Btw, how you can end an instagram post? 'Thanks for watching' or 'for reading'? Is there a short traditional phrase?

Comment: It depends on the reader (and your previous slide). If you talk about something that sounds hard to do/achieve, and after that: "Good luck!", without explanation how to do it, sounds rude. If you try to motivate someone, and then say: "Good luck!", it feels like you care.
"Like and subscribe!", sounds more aggressive to me than "Good luck!".

Answer (score 9):

Usually, "good luck" is used to wish someone success with something. If you were teaching how to make a pie, for example, then saying "good luck" might make sense: you are wishing them success with following your directions. As @Lazar Đorđević said in a comment, it can also be used sarcastically, as if to say "you will need extraordinary amounts of luck in order to be successful with this." Both meanings are listed in [this page from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good%20luck).

However, this phrase can also sound out of place if used in a context where there is nothing to wish success for. For example, if you end a video explaining some science topic with "good luck", people will think "good luck *with what*?" In that case, "thanks for watching" is something I've seen on YouTube, but I don't use Instagram so I don't know if it's used there.

Comment: "Good luck _with that_" is usually sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

"Good luck!" - like other forms of well-wishing e.g. "Have a good time", "Have a nice day", "I hope it works out" - is not considered passive-aggressive, unless there's some other factor in play, e.g. some pre-existing hostility. "Good luck with that" is different: it's generally used to indicate extreme skepticism about the possibility of success - "you want to convince world leaders to renounce state-sponsored violence as a means to solve political problems? Good luck with that!"

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not considered passive aggressive, because you are encouraging them.

Comment: Could you provide some further context to this please? As a native speaker who grew up in a western predominantly English speaking country (Wales) I have quite often seen "good luck" used both passive aggressively and patronisingly including once today.

Comment: You want to surf in the Mediterranean & sunbathe in the Arctic? Good luck with that.

Comment: @MD-Tech - pob lwc!

Comment: @MD-Tech - "You're in with a chance to win the World Cup. Good Luck!." [I don't watch football & only just discovered Wales are in for the first time in many years… but Good Luck in a non-sarcastic way.]